# Python double imports wierd behaviour

Tags: python

So below is the simplified code. I have two files, `main.py` and `test.py`. I declared a  variable called `var` in `main.py` after I imported `test.py`. `test.py` also imports `main.py`.

```py
#file: main.py
import test
var = {}
print('main',hex(id(var)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("main2", hex(id(var)))
    test.func()
```

```py
#file: test.py
import main 

print("in test", hex(id(main.var)))

def func():
    print("in test func", hex(id(main.var)))
```

```
> python main.py
main 0x7fc4fe76fe80
in test 0x7fc4fe76fe80
main 0x7fc4fe9036c0
main2 0x7fc4fe9036c0
in test func 0x7fc4fe76fe80
```

I understand that `var = {}` statement is executed twice, and so `var` is located at `0x7fc4fe9036c0`. However when I call `test.func()` shouldn't `main.var` resolve to  `0x7fc4fe9036c0`? This is not happening, it instead prints old location.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions of your program:

When running main.py, you import test. When test is imported (after creating a first reference to `var`) it creates a new variable (thus new reference) to `var`. When jumping back to initial main.py, it get backs to the first reference of `var`. Same name of variable but different objects.